# Hibernate using a annotations or xml files?

Tags: java, hibernate

Which is more useful in hibernate using annotations or XML??And which is widely used in IT industry and why?
Any answers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

it mainly depends on the type of the project that you are working in.

Usually if your project is a small to medium level then you can use Annotations. by that what i mean is that it will be very easy to maintain and track your mappings this was as annotations are bit complex and difficult to track in the large code set.

If you project is a huge complex project it is suggested you use xml's in such cases. by this you will be able to track the mappings much easily and if use annotations here then it can become very complex.

hope this helps